# mysqldump with federated tables

Tags: mysql, federated-table

I need mysqldump including the data, but in database there are also couple of tables with FEDERATED engine. The mysqldump includes INSERTs for FEDERATED tables too, what makes for exemaple "Duplicate entry" errors (because the table is already filled with data).

I can dump structure and data separately and then remove INSERTs for FEDERATED tables, 
but this is not exactly the same as "make automatically reliable backups"

How to backup and then restore Mysql databases with FEDERATED tables?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at the diff, the solution to this is to compile your own patched version of mysqldump that by default skips INSERTs for FEDERATED tables. I have not tried to apply it myself so YMMV.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32038